# How to support IA-32 for mmap on x86_64?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I need to support an old hardware, which user land library doesn't have source code, but I have the source code for the device driver. Therefore, I have to rewrite the device driver to support IA-32 mode user land binaries.

For the ioctl calls, compat_ioctl is added to support IA-32 in user land. But the 32 bit library makes mmap calls, which returns only half of the address (of course). My question is, is there any support for mmap that's similar to compat_ioctl vs ioctl? If no compat_mmap, how to support IA-32 user land mmap call?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to worry about it.  When your `f_op->mmap()` function is called, it's passed a `struct vm_area_struct` which is already correctly positioned for the calling task.

(On x86-64, the `arch_get_unmapped_area()` function takes care of this - it ensures that the area returned is less than `TASK_SIZE`, and `TASK_SIZE` depends on whether the task has the `TIF_ADDR32` flag set).

Comment: Indeed. And to elaborate, the only reason `ioctl` needs a special version for 32-bit support is because it doesn't have a fixed signature for the kernel to reinterpret; its argument can take on different types, and can point to structure types that differ on 32- and 64-bit. `mmap` has no such issues.